# As (@) pattern in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote my own `take` function in Haskell like this:

```
take' :: (Integral n, Eq a) => n -> [a] -> [a]
take' n lst
    | n <= 0 = []
    | lst == [] = []
    | otherwise = (head lst) : (take' (n-1) $ tail lst)
```

and it works well.

But when I try to write the same function using the as (@) pattern in function arguments, it seems that the function doesn't recognize the second guard option:

```
take' :: (Integral n, Eq a) => n -> [a] -> [a]
take' n lst@(hd:tl)
    | n <= 0 = []
    | lst == [] = []
    | otherwise = hd : (take' (n-1) $ tl)
```

When I try `take' 20 []` in ghci I get the `Non-exhaustive patterns in function take'` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, Špela.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look here:

```
lst == [] = []
```

`lst` can never be equal to `[]`, because you said that `lst = hd:tl`. Instead, you can break that branch out of the guard and into an independent pattern match to get full coverage. (You can also drop the `Eq` constraint once you do that.)

When you invoke `take' 20 []`, it tries to find a pattern that matches that, but you haven't written one: `hd:tl` can't match against `[]`. And after the pattern fails to match, it won't look at the guards for that pattern.

Comment: I totally missed that! Thanks!